# Is there a way to find out if a request was sent using https from a play controller?

Tags: http, playframework, playframework-2.2

I know in older versions, they had the 'secured' field, but that doesn't seem to be there anymore? Is it still possible to find this out? (2.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), there is a de-facto stardard for this kind of information as a HTTP request header. So to obtain this in scala:

```
val x-forwarded-proto = request.headers("X-FORWARDED-PROTO")
```

If this value is "https", it's "secured".

In fact you can look up older Play code [here](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/Http.java) (java).

```
private boolean isRequestSecure() {
            Header xForwardedProtoHeader = headers.get("x-forwarded-proto");
            Header xForwardedSslHeader = headers.get("x-forwarded-ssl");
            // Check the less common "front-end-https" header,
            // used apparently only by "Microsoft Internet Security and Acceleration Server"
            // and Squid when using Squid as a SSL frontend.
            Header frontEndHttpsHeader = headers.get("front-end-https");
            return ("https".equals(Play.configuration.get("XForwardedProto")) ||
                    (xForwardedProtoHeader != null && "https".equals(xForwardedProtoHeader.value())) ||
                    (xForwardedSslHeader != null && "on".equals(xForwardedSslHeader.value())) ||
                    (frontEndHttpsHeader != null && "on".equals(frontEndHttpsHeader.value().toLowerCase())));
        }
```

Strangely enough, it's there again on the [master branch](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala).

Comment: So, this means that I need to set up a proxy server in front of it to add that header? It's just strange that they've added built-in support for SSL in the latest versions yet they still force you to use a proxy server like before by taking away the 'secured' field. Even stranger that they seem to have kept it in the Scala version but not Java. Is this correct?